# Learning programs for Kids

Tags: software-recommendation, education

I am installing Ubuntu in 2 schools that hold at least 1000 kids and wanted to know what programs are available in Ubuntu to teach this Kids. This kids range from ages 4 to 13. Programs that help in math, science, drawing and chemistry would be very good.

Comment: Great to see community outreach with Ubuntu! :-)

Comment: I wish to make this a community question since all answers here a perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the Ubuntu Software Center, Click on Education on the left side, and browse a list of educational programs.  I have most of which installed ( specially the ones listed below)on my kids machine, and they love it.

[image]

- Educational suite GCompris
- Childsplay
- Primary Bundle

Answer (score 2):

[Edubuntu](http://www.edubuntu.org/) is the educational distribution of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [Edubuntu](http://www.edubuntu.org/). You may do this by either downloading and installing the full distro, or getting any or all of the following packages(and recommends/dependencies thereof) and installing upon existing, well-customized (for stability, security, drivers, etc) Ubuntu installations, and removing previous desktop environment choices:

```
edubuntu-desktop
ubuntu-edu-preschool
ubuntu-edu-primary
ubuntu-edu-secondary
ubuntu-edu-tertiary
```

Or any other packages listed [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/edubuntu-desktop).

Answer (score 2):

### You should Try Tux4Kids

This is a big hit with my children and it has 3 main elements. These are all available from the Ubuntu Software Centre.  The interesting thing is that as the children grow so does the level of difficuly.

**

1. Tux Maths
2. Tux Typing
3. Tux Paint

**
Quote below from their website which you can access [here](http://tux4kids.alioth.debian.org/)  You will be able to see screen shots etc

> Tux4Kids develops high-quality software for kids, with the goal of
>   combining fun and learning into an irresistable package. Our software
>   is free: you can download it for use at home or onto hundreds of
>   computers in a school. We support all major platforms, including
>   Windows, Macintosh, and Linux/Unix. Our programs are used by people
>   around the globe, and they have been translated into dozens of
>   different languages. As open-source software, these programs can be
>   freely extended or customized, and they are supported by active
>   communities of volunteer developers.

Answer (score 2):

### KDEdu

is another project worth looking at for the size of your Project. It covers all your bases and a lot more besides.  Floss based on the KDE technologies: students, parents, children, teachers, adults, can freely use it, copy it, and modify.  I have used many of the applications (not all) with great success.

You can access their [website here](http://edu.kde.org/)

Most of the applications are available all Linux distros in their respective Software centres, including Ubuntu that I am aware of and rather than list them here is a screen shot of all the titles

[image]